# Layout behaving weird in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am trying to achieve a chatting app type layout in RecylcerView. Now the only problem is that even though I have set width of View to wrap around text. Inside RecyclerView sometime small words take whole line and sometime the word is fine.

[image]

Green highlight is expected behavior and red is unexpected behavior.

This is the code of cardView

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#00BCD4"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.123">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMessageSent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxWidth="260dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="oh noo"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:maxLines="10" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here is Adapter code

```
public class ChatAdapter extends ListAdapter {

    String reciever,sender;

    public ChatAdapter(String from,String to)
    {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
        this.reciever = from;
        this.sender = to;
    }

    private static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Chat> DIFF_CALLBACK = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Chat>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Chat oldItem, @NonNull Chat newItem) {
            return oldItem.getId() == newItem.getId();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Chat oldItem, @NonNull Chat newItem) {
            return oldItem.getSender().equals(newItem.getSender()) &&
                    oldItem.getReciever().equals(newItem.getReciever()) &&
                    oldItem.getDate().equals(newItem.getDate()) &&
                    oldItem.getMessageIdSent() == newItem.getMessageIdSent() &&
                    oldItem.getMessageRecieved().equals(newItem.getMessageRecieved()) &&
                    oldItem.getTime().equals(newItem.getTime());
        }
    };

    private final int TEXT_MESSAGE_SENT = 0;
    private final int TEXT_MESSAGE_RECIEVED = 1;

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Chat currentChats = (Chat) getItem(position);
        if(!currentChats.getMessageRecieved().equals(""))
        {
            return TEXT_MESSAGE_RECIEVED;
        }
        else if(!currentChats.getMessageSent().equals(""))
        {
            return TEXT_MESSAGE_SENT;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view;
        if(viewType == TEXT_MESSAGE_SENT)
        {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.me_text_message,parent,false);
            return new TextChatSenderViewHolder(view);
        }
        //if reciever is text
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.other_text_message,parent,false);
        return new TextChatRecieverViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Chat currentChat = (Chat) getItem(position);
        switch (holder.getItemViewType())
        {
            case TEXT_MESSAGE_RECIEVED:
                //bind REcievedText viewholder
                TextChatRecieverViewHolder viewHolder = (TextChatRecieverViewHolder) holder;
                if(!currentChat.getMessageRecieved().equals(""))
                {
                    viewHolder.textMessageRecieved.setText(currentChat.getMessageRecieved());
                    viewHolder.textTimeMessageRecieved.setText(currentChat.getTime());
                }
                break;
            case TEXT_MESSAGE_SENT:
                TextChatSenderViewHolder viewHolder2 = (TextChatSenderViewHolder) holder;
                if(!currentChat.getMessageSent().equals("")) {
                    viewHolder2.textMessageSent.setText(currentChat.getMessageSent());
                    viewHolder2.textTimeMessageSent.setText(currentChat.getTime());
                }
                break;


        }
    }

    class TextChatSenderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView textMessageSent,textTimeMessageSent;
        public TextChatSenderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textTimeMessageSent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTimeMessageSent);
            textMessageSent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textMessageSent);
        }
    }

    class TextChatRecieverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView textMessageRecieved,textTimeMessageRecieved;
        public TextChatRecieverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textTimeMessageRecieved = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTimeMessageRecieved);
            textMessageRecieved = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textMessageRecieved);
        }
    }

}
```

**NOTE: I have noticed that layout changes when the message goes out of screen and you scroll back up.**

Comment: I think what's happening is that a view for a longer line is being recycled and used for the short one. Just a guess though.

Comment: @Beko so can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure if that is the cause. You could try playing around with the pool size. Eg. try setting it to 0 `mRecyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, poolsize);` and see how that behaves.

Comment: you should post your adapters code, in there you have a bug (in `onBindViewHolder` method probably)

Comment: @snachmsm i have added adapter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your onCreateViewHolder, keep below lines in else

```
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.other_text_message,parent,false);
    return new TextChatRecieverViewHolder(view);
```

Also keep layout width to

```
wrap_content
```

rather than

```
match_parent.
```

Answer (score 1):

you've messed up [recycling pattern](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/view-recycling-in-android-with-listview/) (link for `ListView` but it describes pattern better than [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) imho) by overriding `getItemViewType` method and letting this method return `-1`. thats not any of view types, but `onCreateViewHolder` MUST return `ViewHolder`, so you are returning `R.layout.other_text_message`. if any message would have 0-length then this empty layout will show up on list

another problem related to wrong recycling implementation is that you are not always calling `setText` inside `onBindViewHolder`, because of inconsistent view types and `if` check (probably unnecessary, as `itemType` is then `-1`). when you understand how recycling works (above linked) you will notice that when you won't ALWAYS call `setText` in `onBindViewHolder` then recycled item may contain text from previous iteration (before scroll) and this duplicated text will show at this `position` (wrongly recycler view)

now your list item view have `android:layout_width="match_parent"` which may "remember" length before recycling, showing set after recycling, something is messing up in here. if you want text wrapping then `TextView` should have set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`. keeping `android:layout_width="match_parent"` (`ContraintLayout`) inside `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` parent (`CardView`) is very unefficient and may cause multiple redrawings/remeasurements, parent probably should also have `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

my advise to you is to getting rid of empty messages BEFORE setting them to adapter - drawing mechanism isn't a place for filtering inproper items (empty messages in your case) not intended to be drawn. return always some known view type and always fully handle it (`onCreate...` and `onBind...` methods), use at least `else setText("");` for clearing text after previous item/text set for this view

Comment: Thank you for your guidance i will look into the link you have provided for better understanding.